# ¿Que le falta al bucle para hacer update en todos los registros recorridos.?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
if( isset($_POST['asistotales']) && !empty($_POST['numsesiones']) )  {

   $asistotales  = $_POST['asistotales']; //valores de arreglo recibido
   $numsesiones  = $_POST['numsesiones'];  //valor recibido de un input


  $n4 = count($asistotales);  //cuenta elementos del array

  $num4_alumno = 1;  //contador de registros de alumno en gpo
  for ($i=0; $i < $n4; $i += 1, ++$num4_alumno) {
    //regla de 3
    $a = $asistotales[$i];
    $regla = $a * 100;
    $asis = $regla/$numsesiones;
             //no funca
             $gpo  = $grupo[$num4_alumno-1];
             $al   = $alumno[$num4_alumno-1];     

            $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE alumno_grupo SET asistencias = '".$a."'
           WHERE idAlumno = $al AND idGrupo = $gpo") or die (mysqli_error($connect));
```

Comment: ¿Podrías ser un poco más claro?¿Que error te da? ¿Que tendría que dar? ¿Qué esta dando actualmente?

Comment: al actualizar, los registros en la tabla, nadamas lo hace con el primero, los valores para los demas registros no los actualiza. Imprimiendo con echo $gpo, $al, si salen los que deberia tomar el WHERE, pero nadamas actualiza la primer fila

Comment: El bucle for no lo cierras. ¿Te lo has olvidado en tu pregunta o no lo cierras en tu código?

Comment: lo olvido cerrar en la pregunta, en el codigo si esta

Comment: ¿Porque le pones $i += 1?

Comment: nadamas como incremento,igual hubiera sido mejor $i ++,

Comment: ¿Como le pasas `$_POST['asistotales']`? Creo que le estarás pasando un valor solamente en vez de un array de valores. Muestra el formulario por favor desde donde se envían los datos.

Comment: Esta como array en html

Comment: Si haces un `var_dump($_POST['asistotales'];)`, ¿que te aparece?

Comment: todo el array, posision por por posision y en donde se captura datos, esos valores que se ingresa los imprime,

Comment: Creo que ya he detectado tu problema. En esta línea `$grupo[$num4_alumno-1];` haces referencia a `$num4_alumno` al cual no le cambias el valor nunca. Aunque sinceramente, como son poco intuitivos los nombres de tus variables no sé que pretendes hacer ahí.

Comment: para obtener el alumno y grupo, que van en el where,

Comment: Si, pero me refiero, cuando sacas $gpo y $al siempre sacas lo mismo $grupo[0] y $alumno[0]. Vale nada, que lo incrementas en el for. Sin embargo creo que el poner el ++ delante es lo que te está haciendo que se descuadre. Pon $num4_alumno++;

Comment: el alumno no porque es el id de tabla, gpo si es el mismo, pero creo que ya esta funcionando

Comment: ¿Al final cual era el problema?

Comment: hacer pre-incremento ++$num_alumno, en ese lugar un incremento++ al final

Comment: muchas, gracias saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se que error tienes, pero yo lo haría diferente:

1. En el `for` sustituir `$i += 1` por `i++` que es la forma habitual de hacerlo y parece más clara.
2. ¿Haces `++$num4_alumno` a continuación para después usar la variable quitándote 1? Si sólo usas esta variable para obtener los valores de `$grupo` y `$alumno`, haz el incremento al final del `for`, si tiene alguna otra función antes de acabar el `for`, justo después de obtener esos valores.
3. Luego para preparar la sentencia, si concatenas las variables en un String entre signos {} PHP reconoce que se trata de una variable y es más rápido,
   por ejemplo:

   "UPDATE alumno_grupo SET asistencias = '{$a}'
              WHERE idAlumno = {$al} AND idGrupo = {$gpo}"

De cualquier forma yo compondría las queries, guardándolas en un array y las ejecutaría después.
Puedes hacer una función que sólo realice la ejecución de un grupo de queries, de este modo puedes meterlas todas en una transacción o no, según el caso, pero sobretodo puedes imprimirlas todas en un momento dado y ver si están correctas sintácticamente o si reciben todos los valores esperados.

Answer (score 0):

En tu bucle `for` cambia `++$num4_alumno` por  `$num4_alumno++`. La primera te hace un pre-incremento por lo que la variable se suma para la iteración que se esté dando en ese momento. Para el segundo caso, se suma uno a la variable `$num4_alumno` pero para la iteración siguiente.